# How can I pass arbitrary template variables into a handlebars helper?

Tags: ember.js

I'm iterating over a plain array in my template:

```
{{#each chapter in chapterList}}
  <li>{{ chapter }} {{ test chapter }}</li>
{{/each}}
```

`chatperList` here is, say, `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. I've made a Handlebars helper:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('test', function(chapter) {
  return this.get('list.selectedChapter') == chapter
    ? 'selected'
    : '';
});
```

but the `chapter` variable in the helper function is simply the string "chapter". How can I access the actual variable itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in Ember (still in the latest v1.0) ... you can't pass a variable to a helper inside an #each or you get:-

```
TypeError: Object.defineProperty called on non-object
```

I just found a workaround using the contents of options.data, but it means you need to quote the object you're passing if it's inside an #each (notice 'color' instead of color below)

Template:

```
<ul>
  <li>{{helpme color 'lorry'}}</li>

{{#each color in model}}
  <li>{{helpme 'color' 'lorry'}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

Helper:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('helpme', function (color, vehicle, opts) {
    var str = color;
    if (typeof opts.data.keywords[color] === 'string') {
        str = opts.data.keywords[color];
    }
    return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString(str + '_' + vehicle);    
});
```

... see my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/continuata/fEffq/13/)

**EDIT:** older versions of Ember use `Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper()` instead of 
`Ember.Handlebars.helper()`

Answer (score 1):

If you want a bound helper you need to use `Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper` which is aliased to `Ember.Handlebars.helper` instead.

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('test', function(chapter) {
  return this.get('list.selectedChapter') == chapter ? 'selected' : '';
});
```

Comment: I get an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object.defineProperty called on non-object`. I think it's because `chapter` is just a scalar, not an object.

Comment: Can you replicate it in a JSBin somewhere?