# Passing Controller Model Properties to Handlebars Helpers

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

I am trying to use a fairly simple Handlebars helper within an `#each` loop going over the items in a controller's model (it's a collection of models supplied by EmberData using the fixtureAdapter). Here's the basic layout of the template:

```
{{#each}}
    ....
    {{#each clusters}}
        <span>{{prettifyTimestampTime cluster_timestamp}}</span>
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Here is my helper (in coffeescript):

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper 'prettifyTimestampTime', (timestamp, options) ->
    d = new Date timestamp
    hours = String(d.getHours() % 12)
    hours = "0#{hours}" if hours.length is 1
    "#{hours}:#{d.getMinutes()}:#{d.getMinutes()}"
```

I originally set this helper on Handlebars itself with `Handelbars.registerHelper`, but I kept getting the string `"cluster_timestamp"` passed in (no matter what I put after `prettifyTimestampTime` in the template, it would get resolved to a String).

I then followed suit and attempted to give [stukennedy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904494/how-can-i-pass-arbitrary-template-variables-into-a-handlebars-helper) a try by wrapping the property in quotes and doing a lookup on `options.data.keywords`, but the key wasn't in that dictionary.

When I to tried to use `Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper` instead, per [Bradley Preist's suggestion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338671/handlebars-passing-object-into-helper), the `timestamp` argument is simply undefined. I do notice that, when I try to access any properties on `options.contexts[0]`, the values they point to are `undefined`, but the keys are there.

I feel completely lost at this point. Any direction is welcome. Is this really a known bug in Ember, as stukennedy has pointed out in the previous SO questions? Having just started with Ember and Handlebars, I would rather have this just be some dumb error on my end, considering how [difficult it was for me to also to set up fixtures with Ember data in the first place](http://www.vinay.io/static/blog/2013/12_17.html). :-P

EDIT: After seeing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004510/whats-the-difference-between-handlebars-helpers-and-ember-handlebars-helpers), I realize why `registerHelper` did not work (because it does not try to associate what is passed in with the property of the current object in context). However, I'm still just as lost since the lookup of the property isn't working. Perhaps this is an Ember Data issue with promises? The only thing that makes me confused about that being the case is that I am using fixtures (no request made), and I am able to get at the property `cluster_timestamp` normally with a normal expression like `{{cluster_timestamp}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use registerHelper, http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/writing-helpers/

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper 'prettifyTimestampTime', (timestamp, options) ->
    d = new Date timestamp
    hours = String(d.getHours() % 12)
    hours = "0#{hours}" if hours.length is 1
    "#{hours}:#{d.getMinutes()}:#{d.getMinutes()}"
```

Comment: Ah cool! That prompted me to look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004510/whats-the-difference-between-handlebars-helpers-and-ember-handlebars-helpers However, this still does not solve my problem, since it does the same thing as `registerBoundHelper`.

Comment: (btw, sorry bout the js2coffee conversion, i'm not sure if it helps or is just fugly)

Comment: the problem is your = sign:)

Comment: Although, that could be a typo, it looks like you're redefining Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper, not calling it

Comment: Ah that was a typo. Sorry about that. Updated the question.

Comment: it seems like your example works, but I'm working on an edit that includes ember-data to see if I can sniff out that it's the culprit.

Comment: I'll setup an ad one as well, is clusters a relationship?

Comment: Hmm this is very strange. It literally just started working. :-\ I'm not sure if there was some caching going on somewhere, but it seems ok now. I'll mark this as the answer and try to get to the bottom of what actually happened. Thanks for the help man!